# ¿Cómo actualizar la tabla2 con la suma de las columnas de la tabla1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Alguien podria ayudarme?
Necesito actualizar una celda de la tabla2 con la suma de un grupo de columnas de la tabla1.
***Estoy trabajando con SQL Server 2008***

**Ejemplo Tabla 1:**

```
select 
sum(val_princ)suma_total
from tabla1 
where 
and fecha <> '0000-00-00'
and contr = '0001723343'
group by fecha,contr
```

**Ejemplo Tabla2:**
*Celdas:* fecha|contr|suma_total|

```
update t2
set t2.suma_total = t1.suma_total
from tabla2 t2
inner join tabla1 t1 (nolock) on t1.contr = t2.contr
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no te entendí mal, buscas actualizar un valor `suma_total` de `tabla2` por `fecha` y `contr`. Algo como esto:

```
update t2
       set t2.suma_total = t1.suma_total
       from tabla2 t2
       inner join (select contr, fecha, sum(val_princ) suma_total
                          from tabla1 
                          where and fecha <> '0000-00-00'
                                and contr = '0001723343'
                                group by fecha,contr
            ) t1
            on t2.contr = t1.contr
            and t2.fecha = t1.fecha
```

- La subconsulta sumariza desde `tabla` por `contr` y `fecha`
- Luego con un `inner join` actualizamos las filas de `tabla2` que coincidan con la subconsulta.

Comment: Patricio Moracho
Gracias por la ayuda.
Lo he probado y he logrado exito.
Saludos,
Bonfim (Brasil)